Is using `exec` in nodejs to convert word file to pdf via `pandoc` a safe way?
I am converting Word files to PDF or HTML for preview page in a server queue jobs (run in nodejs), and use latest pandoc (3.2.1). But I think letting nodejs run a shell command should not a safe way.
Is it safe? Or any other better way to do that? (But it's an extra file processing server and no any permission to access other resources, it will be safe even the code is no safe, LOL)
This is some of my code in queue's job:
const fileKey='uploads/xxxx.docx';// the files are store in storage service's uploads dir
let filePath= this.downloadToLocalTmp(filePath)
let outputPath = tmpdir() + path.sep + (fileKey.substring(fileKey.lastIndexOf('/')));
filePath = filePath.replaceAll(' ', '');// by @joesv 's advice, keep safe `; rm -rf /` => ';rm-rf/' 
outputPath = outputPath.replaceAll(' ', '');

try {
  // using pandoc in next release (1.2.0)
  if (isUsePandoc) {
    // note: pandoc not support doc
    Logger.warn('using pandoc converting');
    const command = `pandoc --embed-resources -o ${outputPath} ${filePath}`;
    Logger.debug(`exec command: '${command}'`);
    const stdout = execSync(command, { timeout: timeout });
    Logger.debug(`exec command stdout: ${stdout.toString()}`);
  } else {
    // note: libreoffice support both doc + docx
    Logger.warn('using libreoffice converting');
    await libreOfficeFileConverter.convertFile(filePath, tmpdir(), 'pdf');
  }
  Logger.debug('convertWordFile finished : ' + filePath);
  return outputPath;
} catch (error) {
  Logger.error('convertWordFile error : ' + error);
  throw error;
}
// ... upload to storage service


Calling pandoc usually means that it has access to the file system, which can sometimes be exploited via specially crafted documents. See the "a note on security" section in the pandoc manual.
A more secure method would be to run pandoc as a server (pandoc server), as this will ensure that pandoc has no access to the file system. Or use the --sandbox flag, which will give you similar guarantees. In that case using exec should be fine.

Unless you can confirm there's nothing malicious in outputPath or filePath, yes.
The snippet of code you shared isn't enough to give a definitive yes nor no.
Using the snippet you shared a malicious person could send any value for the variables including something similar to filePath = "/tmp/file.pdf; rm -rf /".

Thanks , I update the code and in my case those files are all saved on a storage service . It may no be rm -rf.But trully ,it may be a problem so I add filePath = filePath.replaceAll(' ', ''); before exec . Thanks again.

That also wouldn't help. You can set the IFS (internal field seperator) to something else and still execute something in bash or somebody can do something else. I'd recommend checking the answer from @tarleb down below.
